# add rows and columns to atable and display the row and column no

Tags: javascript

I need help in javascript code for dynamically adding rows and columns and displaying the rows and column no. dynamically.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
   <style>
    table, td {
   border:1px solid black;
  }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

<p>Click on each tr element to alert its index position in the table:</p>

   <table>
    <tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
   <td>Click to show rowIndex</td>
   </tr>
   <tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
   <td>Click to show rowIndex</td>
   </tr>
   <tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <td>Click to show rowIndex</td>
 </tr>
</table>

<script>
function myFunction(x) {
alert("Row index is: " + x.rowIndex);
}
</script>

</body>
```

This is what I have tried but I am not sure whether the table rows and columns are generated dynamically and also the column is not renerated and displayed.
Please help.

Comment: Post the code that you tried.

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't add the event handler to each td/tr element manually, use JQuery to add it to all td elements:

```
$('td').click(function(e) {
    console.log($(this).parent().index(), $(this).index());
});
```

Inside the event handler, $(this).parent().index() and $(this).index() will give you the row and column number respectively.

I suggest looking at the JQuery append() or clone() functions for dynamically adding rows/columns, but you haven't really specified exactly what you're trying to do in this respect.